# how to remove always the last three zeros in number

Tags: powerbi, dax

so what i'm currently trying is the following:

I have a table within PowerBI. In this table there is a number column called "duration". Now i want to always remove the last three zeros. The problem i have is that the length of the number is always different so i have to make sure that regardless of the length the last three zeros should be removed.

F. ex:

initial format: 91442000
target format: 91442

initial format: 6000
target format: 6

initial format: 3450000
target format: 3450

How can i achieve that? Your help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Surely just divide by 1000? If your data is a string, can you convert it to a number?